# Cost of memory [de]allocation and potential compiler optimizations (c++)

Tags: c++, memory-management, compiler-optimization, overhead

Is the cost of memory [de]allocation specifically defined? If the cost depends upon the specific compiler being used, is there a general way memory [de]allocation is implemented such that I can reasonably assume the cost?

Is the compiler able to optimize the following code such that the call to 'new' is only done once?

```
char * arr = NULL;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5000000000; ++i)
{
    arr = new char[100000000]
    ... // Process things here
    delete []arr;
}
```

Comment: Well... first of all, which compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is almost certainly not able to perform this optimization. At the lowest level, storage allocation boils down to calls to library functions such as `malloc` (and, one layer deeper, to OS APIs). For the compiler it's not safe to assume that individual `malloc/free` pairs can be left out and their storage reused because their implementation should be outside the optimizer's scope.

Apart from that, I don't think this is a good job for the optimizer. That's something that you, the programmer, can do without special efforts.

There is no standardized cost for memory allocation/deallocation. Generally, allocation/deallocation times may vary greatly (for example it will take significantly longer if the user-space heap implementation is forced to fetch fresh pages from the OS kernel's memory manager).

A reasonable rule of thumb is that small allocations are most likely faster than larger ones and allocations should be slower than de-allocations.

Comment: This loop might show great performance, depending on how malloc is implemented. This unused block might just be sitting in its next free pointer so that new has no work at all.

Comment: The C standard (and by extension, C++) define `malloc` and `free` as part of the implementation. The compiler is given every right to assume semantics. C++ goes further by explicitly sanctioning the replacement of `new` and `delete` (but not `malloc` and `free`), and specifies the requirements on that. Again, the compiler may assume that `new` and `delete` meet their requirements.

Comment: This is interesting... Why should deallocations be slower than allocations?

Comment: @MSalters I don't understand your comment. You are saying that the implementations of **new** and **delete** are defined by the C++ standard? How can they be defined if the standard is hardware-ignorant (and their implementation requires knowledge of the hardware)? Or is this assumption incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler *may* have some settings to optimize your code fragment (which has some errors), but you would have to tell the compiler whether you are optimizing for speed or size.  There is nothing in the standard saying the degree of performance required.

I would factor out the allocation and deallocation because I don't want to rely on the compiler.

Also, since there is no garbage collection in the Standard C++ language, your allocation and deallocation could wreak havoc with fragmented memory (or slow the execution down).

BTW, you error is comparing variable 'i', which is an integer, to a floating point quantity, "5000000000.0".  Note the decimal point.  Good programming practice is to compare integers to integers and floating point to floating point.

Comment: good practice is comparing *signed* integers to *signed* integers etc... `;)`

Comment: @rubenvb:  Sorry, but my pedantic recognition is on low today.

Answer (score 0):

Time for allocating char[100000000] is way smaller compared whit time for setting all elements on 0 (what constructor should do in any case). And if your code writes to each cell allocating is much less expensive than anything else.

And i do not think that there is compiler that makes this working and is calling constructor only.

Comment: -1, compiler should not zero memory. `char` doesn't have a ctor.

Comment: Did not knew that, but still, manipulating each cell is much more expensive than allocating.

Comment: That would be true, but it usually doesn't happen (except in debug builds, and then the memory is typically set to a non-zero debug pattern).